# design model that references interface with EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am stuck on how to design my Recipe model so that it can be used with EF Core. I find it complicated, because the ingredients can be either just a raw material or another recipe.
I have the following models:

```
public interface IIngredient
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    decimal KiloPrice { get; }
}

public class RawMaterial : IIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal KiloPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : IIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal KiloPrice => 
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Ingredient.KiloPrice * x.Quantity) / 
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
    public List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IIngredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Is it even possible to let EF Core map IIngredient? Since that means that when the ingredient is a RawMaterial it can easily just get the KiloPrice, but when it is a Recipe it needs to load the RecipeLines to calculate the KiloPrice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately EfCore cannot map Interfaces. Workaround is to use an Abstract class. I know this is a deviation from the design but this the best you can do.

```
public interface IIngredient
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    decimal KiloPrice { get; }
}


public abstract class BaseIngredient:IIngredient
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    decimal KiloPrice { get; }
}


public class RawMaterial : BaseIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal KiloPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : BaseIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal KiloPrice => 
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Ingredient.KiloPrice * x.Quantity) / 
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
    public List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your usage if you really want to use Interfaces then you can use a backing field with the base class type and a public property with the interface type.

```
public class RecipeLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private readonly BaseIngredient _ingredient;
    public IIngredient Ingredient=>_ingredient;
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

In Your ModelBuilder you will need to specify the PropertyAccessMode as Field.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respons. I am trying to use a base class, but I still can't get the KiloPrice on a Recipe to return the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I dont necessarily need to use an Interface. I am trying to use a base class like you suggested.

```
public abstract class BaseIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal KiloPrice { get; }
}


public class RawMaterial : BaseIngredient
{
    public decimal KiloPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : BaseIngredient
{
    public new decimal KiloPrice =>
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Ingredient.KiloPrice * x.Quantity) /
        RecipeLines.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public int BaseIngredientId { get; set; }
    public BaseIngredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class SqliteDbContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RawMaterial> RawMaterials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BaseIngredient> BaseIngredients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RawMaterial>().ToTable("RawMaterial");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().ToTable("Recipe");
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseIngredient>().ToTable("BaseIngredient");

        modelBuilder.Entity<RawMaterial>()
            .HasBaseType<BaseIngredient>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
            .HasBaseType<BaseIngredient>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseIngredient>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<BaseIngredient>("BaseIngredient")
            .HasValue<RawMaterial>("RawMaterial")
            .HasValue<Recipe>("Recipe");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Ingredient);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Recipe)
            .WithMany(x => x.RecipeLines)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipeId);
    }
}
```

When i save a Recipe with RecipeLines i get an Id contraint error for duplicating the Ingrediënt. The relationship does work when i first save a Recipe and later add RecipeLines to it.

But the real problem i now have, is that the KiloPrice is always 0.

[Ingrediënt using KiloPrice from the BaseIngredient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCaN9.png)